# Cross compile C++ application for target with just C

Tags: c++, dependencies, cross-compiling

I'm cross-compiling a C++ program. But when I try to run on the target computer it can't find the C++ libs (namely libstdc++.so.5).

Is there a way to bundle all the dependencies so I can run on the target computer?

Or do I have to install them on the target computer?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new in C/C++, I did a little research but I link static linking to what I needed. Didn't know it was a trivial question. Static linking solved it. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Of course not. It's trivial if you know the answer, but a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `g++ -static x.cc -o x`. This will link all of your libraries, including libstdc++, into your executable.

Of course, the resulting image will be larger than a dynamically-linked image.